# Negative gain value in stability of a system

Tags: control-system, digital-control

[image]

Let D(z) = k, where k is a constant gain. When I want to find the range of k such that the system is stable, the range of k is included with negative value (eg -5<k<5). My question is, can the gain constant k be a negative value? If can, what will happened to the system?

Comment: You need to know \$\small G_p(s)\$ to answer this.

Comment: Yes, taking T=0.1, gives -7<k<21

Comment: It will be stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If k is negative, then the system may have positive feedback (in some frequency ranges). This is not necessarily unstable (as long as the feedback gain doesn't reach the value of -1), but it would be unusual and not very robust.